# lxml crashes when parsing character from the special font

Tags: python, xml, parsing, fonts, lxml

I try to parse following XML file using lxml.etree.parse(). This XML contains a character from a special font at line 3. This character is from `Dingbats` font - value `0x 7` - a phone pictogram. In Notepad++ it is displayed as `BEL` - white letters inside a black rectangle. I was unable to incert this caracter into the question.

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
      <layer pass="0" class="FontMarker" locked="0">
      <prop k="chr" v="!!!SPECIAL_CARACTER_HERE!!!"/>
      </layer>
</qgis>
```

This character makes lxml (xml crashes as well) crash with the following error:

```
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3193, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:64168)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1548, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91390)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1577, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:91674)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1477, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:90741)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1024, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:87655)
  File "parser.pxi", line 565, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:83243)
  File "parser.pxi", line 656, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:84225)
  File "parser.pxi", line 596, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:83549)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: invalid character in attribute value, line 3, column 14
```

How can I parse a document like this?

**UPDATE:**
[A link to the file itself.](https://filetea.me/default/#t1sRPuSDkoPREa3HMPczqxxtw)

Comment: Do you need that character or is it okay to strip it?

Comment: @pacholik I do need it, but it is better to parse most of the file than nothing at all, so the workaround with exclusion of such characters will be somewhat satisfying.

Comment: It displays as BEL as 7 is the control character representing BEL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character, do you have a link to the font and/or xml file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [here is the link to file](https://filetea.me/default/#t1sRPuSDkoPREa3HMPczqxxtw). Unfortunately I struggle to locate font itself.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example of the  phone pictogram font? xml does not support control characters and that is what seems to be in the source, what are you trying to get from the file?

Comment: An alternative would be to use `BeautifulSoup(open("font_fail.qgs"))`, you will still see it is a control character but at least you can parse the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I wasn't able to find link to dinglabs, but [`wasy10`](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsmath/download/extra-fonts/wasy10/wasy10.html) font pictograms results with the same error. And these characters are needed to be drawn at the map with the other stuff I extract from the .qgs file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that *lxml* can't compete with that. You can use `recover` though, to deal with errors.

> recover - try hard to parse through broken XML

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
>>> tree = etree.parse("/tmp/qgis.xml", parser=parser)
>>> tree.find("layer/prop").attrib
{'v': '', 'k': 'chr'}
```